# How can l get a dynamic tree in terms of depth and number of childs?

Tags: tree, binary-tree, python-3.5

l'm looking to get a dynamic tree in terms of depth and number of child.

Let's note `Tree(D,C)` our tree where `D : depth of the tree` and `C: number of child for each node`

Each node stores two variables :

1- a variable length vector of random values `[25 36 78  1 78 .... 36]`

2- the mean of the vector

For instance : `Tree(D=3,C=3)`  we get :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqmxQ.jpg]

Here is what l tried :

```
def Tree(parent):
    n=len(parent)
    created=[None for i in range(n+1)]
    root=[None]
    for i in range(n):
        createdNode(parent,i,created,root)
    return root[0]
def createNode(ârent,i,created,root):
    if created[i] is not None:
       return 
    created[i]=Node[i]
    if parent[i]==-1:
       root[0]=created[i]
    if created[parent[i]] is None:
       createNode(parent,parent[i],created,root)
    L=created[parent[i]]
    if L.left is None:
       L.left=created[i]
    else
       L.right=created[i]

class Node:
def __init__(self,key):
    self.key=key
    self.left=None
    self.right=None
```

Sorry l'm newbie to tree structure.

Thank you